# Why is the Debugger deleting my code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Using VS2013 Pro, WinForms, the debugger keeps deleting my event handlers. (I place them inside the Form.Designer.cs file)

I've only started noticing it recently and I'm positive I haven't changed any settings.

Can anyone else replicate this or is it just something on my system?

Steps to replicate:

1. Create new project C# WinForms
2. Add a split container > Inside panel two of the Base container, nest another split container.
3. In the Form.Designer.Cs file, hook up a Click event handler to the nested panel 1 container.
4. Run. -Click container - should work fine.
5. Exit Debugger > Change color property of the nest panel 1.
6. Run > Can no longer click?
7. Inspect Code > Event Handler has been deleted?

Comment: `Form.Designer.cs` Is that the one that says "do not modify"? What happens if you put the code in `Form.cs`

Comment: Yeah I know, but I've always written code in there! Keeps it tidy.

Comment: @KidCode And you don't think heeding the warnings that the file shouldn't be manually modified would be a good idea?

Comment: Hashtag irony: the boilerplate stuff goes into the `Xyz.Designer.cs` files to keep the `Xyz.cs` files tidy.

Comment: @Dan I just made a new project, the file doesn't carry that warning (just `InitializeComponent` or whatever it is). But at any rate I imagine the whole file gets rewritten at design time.

Comment: @ta.speot.is On mine (VS2013) there's a comment above that method which says "Required method for Designer support - do not modify..."

Comment: I should have been clearer. I meant the top of the file doesn't carry the warning (like `svcutil`'s "generated by a tool") but `InitializeComponent` does.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Ah, yes - fair one

Comment: Ahh, It appears this only happens on events that are not 'default' to the control. (ie - Ones where if you double click the control it doesn't create the event you want, such as the split container. (That creates an On-Paint event, not a click.)
So I can assume it's okay to add/modify event handlers that are default to the control in the .designer file, but others in my code file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added your event handler manually then anytime you change something from the Designer the Form.Designer.cs is regenerated and will delete your event handlers (the ones added manually in the code)

What you need to do is to add the event handler from the Control properties.

For example if you code this in the Designer:

```
myControl.Click += myClickHandler;
```

it will be deleted anytime you change something in the designer, because the whole .Designer.cs file is regenerated and for some reason the VS is not aware of the event handlers added manually.

You;ll see that if you add the event handler from the Control properties window (in the designer) the generated code will look like this:

```
myControl.Click += new EventHandler(myClickHandler);
```

Another workaround is to add the handler outside the .Designer.cs class, but the easy way is to add the handler from Designer :).